# CiviCRM's Form Processor failing when "User Registration" Form Processor in Caldera Forms is enabled to create the WordPress User

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms, form-processor

I am getting an error in a registration form built with **Caldera Forms** and the integration with **CiviCRM's Form Processor**

**Error**: *Action Create or update phone number failed. Caused by contact_id is not valid: ***"id"****

where "***id***" should be the CiviCRM contact_id, but instead the CiviCRM Form Processor is using ***civicrm_email.id***, and ***not civicrm_email.contact_id***.

The ***CiviCRM Form Processor*** is set up in the following way:

"actions": [

```
    {
        "name": "Contact: Get By Email or Create By Email and Names",
        "configuration": {
            "contact_type": "1"
        },
        "mapping": {
            "email": "input.email",
            "first_name": "input.first_name",
            "last_name": "input.last_name"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Contact: Create or update CiviCRM Fields linked to the CiviCRM Contact",           
        "mapping": {
          "contact_id": "action.get_or_create_by_email.contact_id",
          <more CiviCRM fields to be created/updated based in the input fields of the Caldera 
          Form>
    }
```

]

where ***"contact_id": "action.get_or_create_by_email.contact_id"*** is retrieving the ***civicrm_email.id***, ***not civicrm_email.contact_id*** and consequently I am getting the following ***DB Error***:

*constraint violation: a foreign key constraint fails*

as the Form Processor is trying to create/update fields of the CiviCRM Contact, but there is not contact_id with id = ***civicrm_email.id***.

When I disable the "***User Registration***" Form Processor in the Caldera Form , which creates the **WordPress User**, the process works perfectly. But if this Form Processor is enabled to create the WordPress user, the process fails.

Any clue will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There was a regression in the action-provider extension that contains the code for the "Get By Email or Create By Email and Names" action.

This is fixed in the extension's master branch but a new release has not been tagged yet.